# Conditional maximum likelihood of AR(1) UNIFORM PROCESS

Tags: econometrics, statistics, time-series

Let $Z_t = \phi Z_{t-1} + u_t$ where $u_t \sim uniform[-1,1]$ and $|\phi|<1$ I 
I am facing problems coming up with conditional maximum likelihood estimate of an AR(1) process with **uniform errors**. I want to compute the conditional maximum likelihood estimate of $\phi$. Specifically, I want to see how I can come up with:

- the joint distribution of the uniform random variables conditional on $Z_1$ (e.g. if initial values for $Z$ where $Z_1 = 0.3$, $Z_2 = 0.8$ and $Z_3 = 1.2$, $Z_4 = 1.6$) how can I get the joint distribution

  - What will be the conditional maximum likelihood estimate of $\phi$

I have tried to approach the problem as follows but end up with no solution:
Conditional on $Z_1$, $Z_2$ is distributed as:

$Z_2 \sim uniform[-1 + 0.3 \phi, 1 + 0.3 \phi]$ marginal distribution $ 1/2$

$Z_3 \sim uniform[-1 + 0.8\phi, 1 + 0.8 \phi$ marginal distribution $ 1/2$

$Z_4 \sim uniform[-1 + 1.2\phi , 1 + 1.2\phi$ marginal distribution $ 1/2$

I got the marginal distribution to be (1/2) for all of them got confused on how I can maximize the likelihood if the marginal distribution of the variables is not dependent on $\phi$, I am sure I missed something, any suggestion:

Assuming the processes are independent, I took the joint distribution to be a multiple of the individual marginals (1/2), but I think this is somehow wrong and it should depend on the interval they can exist together.

$ f_{z_2,z_3,z_4} = \prod 1 I(x_1 < \phi < x_n)$ but I couldn't get how I should approach this indicator function and also identify what should be the common interval where the marginal distributions overlap.

Comment: While this is a good question, I feel like you would get more responses in cross validated.

Comment: thanks I will also post it on cross validated.

Comment: You should note, however, that this is a perfectly acceptable question for economics.SE. It's up to you to post it here or there. See here: https://economics.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic

Comment: @jmbejara, you might know better than me what is on topic and what is not, but this looks like a statistical question without an econometric flavour. There is a difference between econometrics and statistics, and this one looks purely statistical. (To briefly illustrate the difference, an econometric question would be dealing with identification, instrumental variables, endogeneity, etc.) I would be cautious about the overlap between Economics SE and Cross Validated and would be inclined to keep the statistical questions on one site, i.e. Cross Validated.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is an exact duplicate of https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/318118/conditional-maximum-likelihood-of-ar1-uniform-process